# Why does the tombstone contain the `marked_deleted` timestamp when it could rely on `liveness_info`?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am reading http://www.beyondthelines.net/databases/cassandra-tombstones/ where

```
INSERT INTO locations (
  address,
  status,
  properties
) VALUES (
  'D3-DJ-21-B-02',
  'damaged',
  null
);
```

yields

```
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "D3-DJ-21-B-02" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 18,
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2017-01-28T11:58:59.160898Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "status", "value" : "damaged" },
          { "name" : "properties", "deletion_info" : { "marked_deleted" : "2017-01-28T11:58:59.160897Z", "local_delete_time" : "2017-01-28T11:58:59Z" } }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Why does the tombstone contain the `marked_deleted` timestamp when it could rely on `liveness_info`?**

Comment: In your example the liveness_info belongs to the row and the deletion_info belongs to the "properties" cell (inserting a null will create a tombstone). I recommend reading this article on tombstones - [About Deletes and Tombstones in Cassandra](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html)

Comment: @Horia Thanks. Read the article. It was great! That said, I did not answer why these are two different timestamps when the query is executed at the same time. Some disk space would be able to be saved if only using a single timestamp.